# Get output into my application from another Java Console

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, console-application

I need to get the output (displayed data) from a Java Console App to be parsed through my VB.net application.  I also need to send input to the application.  How can I accomplish both of these tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should populate the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) object, start the process for your Java Console app, and read the output of it:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

// specify the address of your java app
startInfo.FileName = "JVM_PATH_HERE.EXE";

// input for your java app
startInfo.Arguments = "-jar JAVA_APP_PATH_HERE.exe";

// do not show your java app window
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

// redirect standart input/output for your needs
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using (Process javaProc = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    StreamReader oReader2 = p.StandardOutput;

    // get results from your java app
    string javaResults = oReader2.ReadToEnd();
    oReader2.Close();

    // do whatever your like with results;
    AnalizeResults(javaResults);
}
```

Comment: Instead of JAVA_APP_HERE.EXE under the FileName, he should probably put the path to the installed JVM, and under the Arguments place first -jar and the location of his java executable